# Highcharts : Spiderweb chart null values behaviour

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a Spiderweb chart.

JSFiddle for reference : 
http://jsfiddle.net/2ywqfgfr/

The underlying data has null value for `Administration` category.

Using the `connectNulls : true` property, I can join the null values BUT is there a way that once the `Allocated Budget` series is deselected, the `Administration` category is removed from the chart for `Actual Spending`.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1:**
To add more clarity the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xvf9ktqb/1/ has been added with an extra category `Others`.

There are 7 categories in total. When `Allocated Budget` is deselected, only 6 categories are shown in the chart for `Actual Spending`.

Since `Others` is the last category, this behaviour is correct. But if any in-between category is missing, then everything gets jumbled due to the incorrect ordering of the data points. http://jsfiddle.net/xvf9ktqb/2/ has `development` category missing and tooltip shows incorrect labels.

Hence `null` values have to be included for missing categories.

Comment: How you would like to remove category from one serie and print in second serie? Could you supply a mockup?

Comment: @SebastianBochan: I've updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: Summarising, when at least one null point exists then whole category (and points from other series) should be invisible, correct?